# Tutorial for ASP.NET using FB C# SDK 5.0.25 (RTW)

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

anyone can show me link or share with many of us who faced problems in using and understanding the latest 5.0.25 (RTW) release which I don't find any useful documentation/tutorial for beginners.

I need to know how to create 1 simple ASP.NET website that has a FB login button on top of an existing login based on the below (flowchart and link)

My site uses Facebook and my own Registration

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/user_registration/flows/

I'm not sure what to use and which dll to add after I downloaded the 5.0.25 (RTW) assemblies file.

I'm using VS 2008 with .NET 3.5, need to create a ASP.NET Website Project.

I've already got an App ID and I'm ready to develop. Please help!

Comment: I will try to find some time (hopefully I still have VS 2008 installed). WebForms, right?